# ipython rolling log

Tags: ipython

I want to have last 500Mb worth of ipython input and output saved to a file

The saving described above should be able to get around instances when I have to kill ipython. For example, saving based on a timer

I want to have this file reloaded (not re-executed) at startup. The file then gets updated in a rolling fashion

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPython already logs your input - it's stored in `history.sqlite` in your profile folder (run `ipython locate profile` to see where that is). To turn on output logging as well, edit `ipython_config.py` and search for 'db_log_output'. This captures output resulting from the displayhook (with the `Out [n]:` prompt), not printed output.

To look at history from a previous session, you can use `%hist ~1/1-10` (lines 1-10 of the session before the current one). It also works with magic commands like `%rerun`, `%recall` and `%save`.

If you want it recorded to a text file, have a look at the `%logstart` magic.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the response. I'm a newbie with ipython. How can I tie the above configurations to achieve what I need? Specifically - 1. Is there a way to load a text file into ipython as terminal history? 2. Can I save a portion of terminal history to a file on a timer?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? IPython already reloads the last 1000 commands you entered into the terminal history.

Comment: If ipython were used as a 'system' scripting terminal like bash, then info(commands) >> info(output). So storing cmd(s) and having them easily recallable and re-executable (%hist, %rerun, %recall and %save) makes sense.  
  


But if you want to use it as a 'data processing' terminal like R/matlab (which is how I use it) info(commands) ~ info(output). I have no particular use for a command without the associated output and vice-versa. In fact, what I want when I restart my work after day/week end is to recollect where I was in the course of solving a problem

Comment: Hence, I'd like a log of my previous work appear as my 'terminal history'. The problem with an external log file is that it tends to grow very large over time. Hence, I need it to be 'rolling'. Also I do not know how to reload it and make it appear as terminal history

Comment: Well, if you enable `db_log_output`, then it stores the output, and you can just do `%hist -po ~1/1-10` to see what you were doing. It doesn't grow that fast, but there's a new `ipython history trim` command coming in 1.0 that cuts the database to the last 1000 entries.

Comment: OK. I think %hist -po that will almost get me there. But, I do wish 'history trim' could be configured to run in an automated fashion. From my reading of 'class HistoryManager', it seems to be possible to cache no. of lines currently in db and just drop old 10% when a threshold is crossed. Thx

Comment: You're welcome to write code to do that. I can't guarantee we'd include it in IPython, but you could probably distribute it as a separate script.